# Prevent Google Plus website snippet widget from following noscript tags

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one, noscript

This Questions title could also be: Using a no-javascript-dependent meta tag. How?

I'm using the script I created, [here](http://www.perfecterrordocs.com) on most of the sites, I manage.

In order to test if the user has JavaScript disabled, I use the following code (normally on the `index.php` page of the site):

`<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/error_documents/javascript-test.php"></noscript>`

which works perfectly, to execute *only* if the user has javascript disabled, except for one thing...

Google+ social website snippet widget follows the link within the meta tag and displays *its* Structured Data instead of the page it's supposed to (i.e. the page with the original `<noscript>` tag).

How to prevent this, and refresh the Google social snippet widget to show the correct data?

Comment: If you redirect your users (why?) then you also redirect bots. If you want to handle bots in another way than normal users, this is called "cloaking", as you are hiding contents from the search engine bot. Google for example gives you a penalty for such a behavior. Also, a redirect using a meta tag is a bad idea for even more reasons…

Comment: I'm only trying to redirect users that don't have JavaScript enabled, only to inform them it's not working, and educate them on how to fix the issue. that's all. visit [this page](http://www.perfecterrordocs.com/error_documents/javascript-test.php) with your browsers JavaScript 'Disabled' then 'Enabled' to understand.

Comment: OT: You shouldn't try to educate your users how to turn on JS – just deliver a normal website (you know, one that doesn't require JS to display error pages). Most user can't do anything, if the JS wasn't loaded. It happens to me again and again when rinding on the subway and having a bad  UMTS connection. Most websites do get loaded, but some images and half of the JS are missing sometimes. Other users are behind company firewalls that block huge amount of JS.

Comment: Instead of automatically doing the redirect, put some text in the noscript tag explaining the issue and have a link so the users can choose to follow it or not.

Comment: @abraham that's a good idea, but unfortunately some users visit your site without JavaScript just to see how many things break, and if it's hackable, or not. For this very reason, I try to disable form submit buttons using html attribute `disabled=disabled`, and re-enable them, by removing the attribute via JavaScript. That way the page is, in essence, dead, without JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. then hide the form with CSS and show it with JS, if someone has JS disabled they still won't see the form. Plus a disabled form is not security so it shouldn't matter what the form state is, the backend needs to be secure.